# Trouble retrieving Active Directory computer description

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-2.0

When I run:

```
$computer = Get-ADComputer -SearchBase 'OU="Windows 7 Machines",OU="Devices",dc=blah,dc=Local' -Filter 'name -like "computerName"' -Properties Description
```

I'm able to get the AD description using

```
$computer.Description
```

My question is: how do I get the computer description without using the `-Properties Description` argument?

```
$computer = Get-ADComputer -SearchBase 'OU="Windows 7 Machines",OU="Devices",dc=blah,dc=Local' -Filter 'name -like "computerName"'
```

How do I get the description from the `$computer` variable here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `Get-ADComputer` or some other LDAP query tools?  You don't.

Specifying `-Properties Description` is what tells the `Get-ADComputer` cmdlet to request the `description` field from the LDAP server.  If you don't specifically request it, the LDAP server does not send it in the response back to the cmdlet.  You must specify any fields you want beyond the defaults, and description is not a default field.

I mean sure, ok, you could say `-Properties *`, and that technically answers your question, but then you're asking for *every property* (this is bad; it takes much longer).